# Security scan dependencies with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to the SonarQube.

I am using SonarQube to security scan my Java source code. I am also using Trivy to security scan my Docker container where I pack my Java app for deployment.

I deploy my code on JBoss and Tomcat web servers.

So, I have SonarQube to security scan my source code and Trivy to security scan my Docker image, but now I need something to security scan my code's dependencies (JARs).

Can SonarQube scan dependency Apache libraries and report which dependencies contain security flows and needs to be replaced with newer versions? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [dependency-check](https://owasp.org/www-project-dependency-check/) project is what you're after; there are Grade and Maven plugins to make using it easier and it can be integrated with [SonaqQube](https://github.com/dependency-check/dependency-check-sonar-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Trivy plugin to convert Trivy results into SonarQube format and import it as external issues report to SonarQube: https://github.com/umax/trivy-plugin-sonarqube

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).